# Get week number starting from monday from 04:00 am in the year

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, week-number

I use this code, but get week starting from Sunday.

```
Select DATEPART(week,s.Calculationdate) weeknumber, s.Calculationdate
FROM sales.orders s
WHERE s.Calculationdate >= '2020-01-01 04:00:00' and s.Calculationdate < '2020-05-01 04:00:00'
AND s.Calculationdate< CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(),23) + '04:00:00' AS datetime)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `DATEPART` you can use `WEEK` and `ISO_WEEK`:

```
SELECT DATEPART(WEEK,'2020-04-05')
SELECT DATEPART(ISO_WEEK,'2020-04-05')
```

and you can get even more control setting the first day of a week using:

```
SELECT @@DATEFIRST
SET DATEFIRST 1; -- day of a week
SELECT @@DATEFIRST
```

Comment: Thanks, ISO_WEEK gave me the required result. Can you help me once more,.                  How can I use the time with ISO_WEEK, I want that my days starting from 04:00:00, like this from 2020-01-01 04:00:00 to 2020-01-02 04:00:00

Comment: Sure, what's the issue?

Comment: How can I use the time with ISO_WEEK, I want that my days starting from 04:00:00, like this from 2020-01-01 04:00:00 to 2020-01-02 04:00:00

Comment: Could you share some sample data and desired output? Also, why do you need this - it's like changing how 24-hours day is deifned.

Comment: I need to get UTC+0, that's why i need that my days start from 04:00:00.                                      I mean i want like this week_number-1.              When i have date like below                                                                      Calculationdate- 2020-01-06 03:15:37

Comment: If your date is not stored in UTC, you can try converting it to the corresponding time zone. There area different techniques -` SELECT GETUTCDATE(), CAST(SWITCHOFFSET(GETUTCDATE() AT TIME ZONE 'Pacific Standard Time', 0) AS DATETIME2(0))`